# Google Sheets Transpose last columns values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this table in Google Sheets

```
Month   1  2  3  ...
1      20 30 45
2         32 47
3            53
...
```

How do I Transpose the last value of each columns into this?

```
Month  lastValue
 1       20
 2       32
 3       53
```

...

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a sample formula. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, in your situation, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=BYROW(B2:D,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,x),","),1))))
```

- In this formula, in order to start no empty cell, I used `TEXTJOIN` and `SPLIT`. And, the 1st cell is retrieved. I used this with `BYROW`.
- As another approach, this formula `=BYROW(B2:D,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(x,x<>""),1))))` might be able to be also used.

#### Testing:

When this formula is used in your provided situation, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)